# Simple CSS reverse transition

Tags: css, transition, reverse

CSS beginner here

```
img {
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
img:hover {
    position: relative;
    top: -5px;
}
```

On hover, this transition works fine.
But when you mouse away again there is no effect, the 'reverse' transition is instant.
How to achieve 0.5s on reverse transition too?

Comment: that should work. Might be something else breaking it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Will look further into it. Could be classes breaking it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply move `position: relative` from the `:hover` rule to the `img` rule. When not hovered, the `img` element isn't being positioned relatively. The `top` property doesn't do anything on a statically positioned element.

```
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
img:hover {
    top: -5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for answering. This is a solution to my problem! :)

Comment: Sorry, new to this site. Done. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
img:hover {
    top: -5px;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This issue has been corrected. Please take a look.

```css
img {
  width: 136px;
  height: 23px;
  -webkit-transition: width 2s;
  /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
  transition: width 2s;
}
img:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div style="background-color:red;">
  <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png">
</div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devrastogi/72sbc0ej/)

Comment: How does it relates to question?

Comment: I have just set a jsfiddle link to help with demo.

Comment: Your answer should contain all relevant code and an explanation as to what your solution is. Don't put a link to an offsite resource in the comments as part of it. Then there's also the issue of how your code is different from that in question.

Comment: 1. I understand it. The code there is not related to the question. 2. You have to include code as a snippet into you answer.